Trying to start Apache Superset, and get "services.superset-node.env_file.0 must be a string"
The Superset docs say to clone the repo, and run docker compose up. When I do that:
$ docker compose up
services.superset-node.env_file.0 must be a string

I am on OS X version 12.7.5, Docker version 20.10.22 (build 3a2c30b), git commit hash 36b1535199222456d87b9317ac3654fcdad5f6f5 (June 19 2024).

I am leaving this as a reference for others.  My old version of docker was not working. I updated to the latest docker (Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b) and it works.
